# HTML5 Player Framework - fallback to Silverlight in IE8 not working

Tags: html, silverlight, video, azure

HI I am trying to get a video to play from Azure Media services and am using the HTML5 Player Framework (https://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HTML5%20Player&referringTitle=Documentation)

I have tested the example on IE8 and it correctly falls back to Silverlight (http://smf.cloudapp.net/html5/html/fallback.html)

However when I try to implement my own its does not work correctly.  See code snippet 1 below
- It plays the HTML5 video in all compatible browsers
- In IE8 it shows a black screen with a white loading icon
- If I change the code and force it to play in Silverlight (see code snippet 2) then it will play in Silverlight in all browsers
- These leads me to believe that the video is encoded correctly on the server

***However, I notice when they have a fallback example the fallback is an MP4 but when they show Silverlight only its a smooth URL Manifest file.  Not sure what is happening there.  I am using dynamic packaging with Azure media services and have tried using both mp4 and mianifest***

Thoughts and help please

**Code Snippet 1 - Does not fallback**

```
<video id="myVideo" class="pf-video" width="480" height="320" controls="controls" poster="../media/mdot_traderLogo.png">
        <source src="https://tradertest.blob.core.windows.net:443/asset-124e89b8-ef6a-492d-9022-30a94b9b1341/trader_H264_1900kbps_AAC_und_ch2_96kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&se=2015-02-05T19%3A43%3A24Z&sr=c&si=88de031a-6525-45f1-9950-9a6015dfea8b&sig=o052OQGNcatp4zWRSeGdIPrmaJ5SfyOQm0PAw5uzT%2Fo%3D" type='video/mp4' />
        <object class="pf-silverlight" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="480" height="320" data-poster="../media/bigbuck.png">
            <param name="source" value="../xap/ProgressiveDownloadPlayer.xap" />
            <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
            <param name="onLoad" value="onSilverlightLoad" />
            <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
            <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
            <param name="enableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
            <param name="windowless" value="true" />
            <param name="InitParams" value="scriptablename=Player,autoplay=false,mediaurl=http://tradertest.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/b51f74c6-4de7-4218-94f7-2f0b8ac58358/trader.ism/manifest" />
            <div class="pf-static">
                Silverlight is not installed or a later version is required.
            </div>
        </object>
    </video>
```

**Code snippet 2 - silverlight only - does work**

```
<object id="myVideo4" class="pf-silverlight" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="480" height="320" data-poster="../media/bigbuck.png">
    <param name="source" value="../xap/SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap" />
<param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
<param name="onLoad" value="onSilverlightLoad" />
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="false" />
<param name="enableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
<param name="windowless" value="true" />
<param name="InitParams" value="scriptablename=Player,autoplay=false,mediaurl=http://tradertest.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/b51f74c6-4de7-4218-94f7-2f0b8ac58358/trader.ism/manifest" />
    <div class="pf-static">
        Silverlight is not installed or a later version is required.
        </div>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage this project at Microsoft and can try to help. I'm not totally clear on your question though. To clarify, you know that when using Silverlight we default to smooth streaming but when we fall over to HTML5 we are forced to do a progressive download of the media file instead because smooth streaming is not supported, correct? Are you saying that the detection code is failing to fall back to SL when played in IE8 and is instead trying to render a video tag?

Thanks,
Mike - miked --at-- microsoft.com

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for the quick reply.

Sorry if the post was not clear.I am new to all these streaming options so bear with me.

Code Snippet 1 above is how I want it to work, I want it to use HTML5 when possible and when not possible (IE8) I would like it to fall back to Silverlight.

The detection code does seem to be working as I can see in the network tab in IE8 it is making a call out to the manifest URL.

Code snippet 2 was just to prove that when I set it up for Silverlight only it works which leads me to believe the encoding is okay.

Does this make it any clearer?

Comment: Another point of note, there are 3 seperate network calls to the manifest URL and they all return a status code of 304